# Pop up text boxes on hover on revolution slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, revolution-slider

I am building a website that has a 3d front and back skeleton image using the revolution slider on a wordpress website.

I want to make it to when you hover over a specific area or point an text box pops up with text in it. I'm not sure how that is possible using the revolution slider.

Comment: i see that you have 5 questions with no accepted answers. to accept an answer you just hover beside the answer and click the tick beside it. you can only accept one. you gain two points when you accept an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this - requires a small bit of jquery

```js
$("#container > article:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $('#container > article:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#container');
}, 3000);
```

```css
body {
    font: normal 16px/1.5 Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 .5em;
}

#container {
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width: 480px;
    max-height:240px;
   overflow:hidden;
}



/*
 * Caption component
 */
.caption {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    /* Only the -webkit- prefix is required these days */
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);
}

.caption::before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: transparent;
    transition: background .35s ease-out;
}

.caption:hover::before {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.caption__media {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.caption__overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
            transform: translateY(100%);

    transition: -webkit-transform .35s ease-out;
    transition:         transform .35s ease-out;
}

.caption:hover .caption__overlay {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
}

.caption__overlay__title {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -webkit-calc(-100% - 10px) );
            transform: translateY( calc(-100% - 10px) );

    transition: -webkit-transform .35s ease-out;
    transition:         transform .35s ease-out;
}

.caption:hover .caption__overlay__title {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
}

article{max-width:480px; max-height:240px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

    <article class="caption">
        <img class="caption__media" src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6088/6128773012_bd09c0bb4e_z_d.jpg" />
        <div class="caption__overlay">
            <h1 class="caption__overlay__title">Alaska</h1>
            <p class="caption__overlay__content">
                Alaska is a U.S. state situated in the northwest extremity of the North American continent. Bordering the state is Canada to the east, the Arctic Ocean to the north, and the Pacific Ocean to the west and south, with Russia (specifically, Siberia) further west across the Bering Strait.
            </p>
        </div>
    </article>

        <article class="caption">
        <img class="caption__media" src="http://www.planetware.com/photos-large/USMI/michigan-ann-arbor-university.jpg" />
        <div class="caption__overlay">
            <h1 class="caption__overlay__title">Michigan</h1>
            <p class="caption__overlay__content">
               Some dummy text for testing
            </p>
        </div>
    </article>

    </div>
  

</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7GvV2/423/

Comment: for how to include jquery into wordpress see https://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/

Comment: Yes this is correct except that my image will have multiple points on it that need this pop up effect. Also when the text pop shows up I only want it to be only a portion of the image that the text shows up not the whole thing.

So for example the skeleton will be a front and back and have multiple points on it. When i hover over the point i want a pop up box of text. Here is the image example http://192.254.166.37/magrehab

Comment: @KaushalKakadia what you want is a bit complicated. it's kinetic text. check out http://campolar.me/2010/05/kinetic-text-animation-using-jquery/ the demo is a bit mad but you'll get the idea. pls accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry that I won't be answering to your **exact** question, but I do believe that I still will be helpful.

I've used this exact functionality in most of my Wordpress sites and everytime I'm doing this with a free Wordpress plugin called text-hover. https://wordpress.org/plugins/text-hover/

It works like a charm! I hope I've been helpful!